# here is my firebase datastructure. how to fetch user data and make table in html

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pie-chart

This is the database structure i have i want to get logged in user data.
i want to make table of data: Columns: Date,Status

[image]

Also i want to make percentage piechart wheel by calculating success and failure rate. but not able to get data from firebase.

I tried this but not working. I'm able to log in log out successfully. I'm also able to add data in firebase only once per date.
I'm just not able to fetch and show in table.
Here's what i tried:
`

```
// Get the user's attendance records
firebase.database().ref("attendance").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  // Get the attendance data
  var attendanceData = snapshot.val();
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  // Display the attendance history
  for (var email in attendanceData) {
    var attendance = attendanceData[email][userId];
    if (attendance) {
      for (var date in attendance) {
        var status = attendance[date].status;
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.innerHTML = `<td>${date}</td><td>${status}</td>`;
        attendanceHistoryTable.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a data structure like this:

```
attendance: {
  user: {
    "$uid": {
      "$date": {
        Status: "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And from this you want to show the status per date for the current user.

If that's indeed the use-case, you can do this with:

```
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
const attendanceRef = firebase.database().ref("attendance");
const userRef = attendanceRef.child("users").child(userId);
userRef.once("value", function(userSnapshot) {
  userSnapshot.forEach((dateSnapshot) => {
    const status = dateSnapshot.child("Status").val();
    console.log(`User: ${userSnapshot.key}, Date: ${dateSnapshot.key}, Status: ${status}`);
    ... // TODO: add the data to the HTML as you're already doing
  });
});
```

The main changes I made here:

- This only loads the data for the current user, instead of for all users.
- This code uses the built-in `forEach` operation of a `DataSnapshot`.
- This code gives more meaningful names to the variables, so that it's easier to parse what is going on.
- This code uses `"Status"` rather then `status`, since that's the key in your database screenshot too.